# Allowing a user to control and/or view their own revisions

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a way to allow a user to view and/or edit only their own revisions?  I don't want another user to be able to view other people's revisions.  Is there a module for this?

Answer (score 1):

The [revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module gives you this ability:

> Revisioning is a module for the configuration of workflows to create,
>   moderate and publish content revisions.

Comment: Unfortunately this module is not able to do what I want: allow a user to control and view his or her own revisions.  This module allows me to publish and unpublish various revisions, but it is still too general and everyone can see it.  Any other suggestions?